# ASP.NET Webforms Binding a List of Links To a User Based on there Role, for a View .ASPX

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, model-binding

I have been trying to figure this out for about an hour now. I am familiar with how to do this in MVC, but my company uses Webforms and trying to think in terms of WebForms, this problem is beating me.

Well I am using ASP Identity, Roles and the Entity Framework, what I need to do is figure out how to get a list of hyperlinks that a user is assigned to based on their role to display when the page loads. I have the hyperlinks stored in the database, which navigates to different part of the site.

The code I am using in the code behind and the .aspx view is listed below.

```
namespace Website
{
    public partial class MemberCenter : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected Website.Models.WebsiteDbContext _db = new Website.Models.WebsiteDbContext();

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   
        }

        public IQueryable<Website.Models.RoleLink> GetData()
        {

            if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("admin"))
            {
                RoleLink roleLinks = _db.RoleLinks.Where(rl => rl.RoleId == 1).FirstOrDefault();
            }

            return _db.RoleLinks;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the part for the .aspx page. I know this is pretty self explanatory with MVC but with Webforms how would I pass a list of links to the page and display the, if I had more that one list.

```
<div>
    <asp:ListView ID="linkList" runat="server"
        DataKeyNames=""
        ItemType="Website.Models.RoleLink"
        SelectMethod="GetData">
        <EmptyDataTemplate>
            No links associated with this user
        </EmptyDataTemplate>
        <LayoutTemplate>
            <table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>
                            <asp:HyperLink runat="server" href="Administration/ToolUpCMS/Users/" ID="distribLink">Tool Up CMS</asp:HyperLink>
                        </th>
                        <th>&nbsp;</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr runat="server" id="itemPlaceholder" />
                </tbody>
            </table> 
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <tr>

            </tr>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:ListView>
</div>
```

Comment: I di not mean to select asp-classic

Comment: loop through your list(s). on each loop, create a new control and set its properties, then attach each control to the page. (or have the controls on the page and just set properties, like href, as you loop.)